# How to "follow"Java software executing

Tags: java

I am facing with a software made in Java. This program is a group of jar called in a flow after the first startup.jar

There is a way or method to follow executing and know which class is currently running without inject a log class inside all class files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably [JavaSnoop](http://www.aspectsecurity.com/tools/javasnoop):

[image: JavaSnoop]

Source code and binaries available from [here](https://code.google.com/p/javasnoop/).

Presentation and demo video available [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipuSmbxBxKw).